# what is the major difference between Fragments and content view

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I tried to clarify my doubt in android developer website but I couldn't understand it clearly. My question is if content view can be used to represent a part of a view like a fragment then why do we use fragments? Can you explain the major difference between fragments and content views.

Answer (score 1):

Two different terms.

Content View in simple terms is the view where the content of your activity is displayed.By calling:

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

in your activity, you set content (a layout created in XML or dynamically) to your view (the rectangular area of your screen that is responsible for drawing and event handling, in other words your screen)

[See this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28int%29)

Fragments on the other hand are modular pieces of an Activity and exist within the Activity or several others and may or may not define its own view layout.
[see this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

> My question is if content view can be used to represent a part of a view like a fragment then why do we use fragments?

AFAIK, Content views do not represent a part of a view, they are the view.

Comment: If I am not wrong, view divides content view. Is it so?

Comment: Can we implement master-detail flow without using fragments?

Comment: Yes, you can use views to give an apperance of a line(divide) in a content view.As for your second question,am sure a more advanced Android programming can implement a master-detail flow without Fragments but that's just 're-inventing the wheel in my opinion.One of the main uses of Fragments is for implementing master-detail flows.